# Sequelize transaction with promise.all fails to rollback when one promise rejects

Tags: javascript, node.js, transactions, sequelize.js, es6-promise

I have a simple function that uses the result of an initial database call in three other functions wrapped by a Promise.all

```js
app.post('/doSomething', (req, res) => {
    return sequelize.transaction(t => {
        return doFirstThing(req, {transaction: t})
        .then((result) => {
            return Promise.all([
                                firstPromise(result, {transaction: t}),
                                secondPromise(result, {transaction: t}),
                                thirdPromise(result, {transaction: t})
                              ])
            .then(finished => { return finished })
        })
    })
    .then((good) => {
        console.log("everything went well, commit")
    })
    .catch((bad) => {
        console.log("something messed up, rollback")
        console.log(bad)
    })
})
```

What happens is, the `thirdPromise` fails, and my console looks something like this:

```
Executing (527b02fc366524a762db): BEGIN TRANSACTION;
Executing (default): doFirstThing
Executing (default): firstPromise
Executing (527b02fc366524a762db): ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
Executing (default): secondPromise
something messed up, rollback
thirdPromise failed
```

The issue here is that, the results of `doFirstThing, firstPromise` and `secondPromise` are all being committed to the database, even though it is supposed to rollback.

I have tried both including a `.catch` on the Promise.all, as well as excluding the `.then` on the Promise.all.

Comment: Promise.all will commit all your promises, it rejects when the first error occurs. If you want to rollback transactions and you are using SQL, why don't you just create some triggers?

Comment: I only want it to rollback if the promise is rejected, which in this case, the third promise is rejected. It was my understanding that if anything in a transaction fails, the entire thing should rollback. Promise.all ignores the transaction?

Comment: @Colin sorry, I edited the question to include that the function calls inside the promise.all are included in the transaction.

Comment: Promise.all only helps you to handle all your resolves in one place and if there is any reject, it catches the first reject. It won't roll back anything, if you need to roll back, you need to do it manually in your catch block. If this is about a database transaction, I think you'd better to roll back transactions at database level.

Answer (score 0):

Use Promise.allSettled method. It waits for all promises to complete and returns the result of all promises in an array.
Make an array of all db writes and pass the same transaction to each. Then await Promise.all settled. Then check if all promises are resolved. If they are commit transaction else rollback.